# Have you seen this golden ratio construction before with three squares (or just two) and circle ?Geogebra gives PHI or 1.6180.. exactly

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, golden-ratio

Geogebra gives PHI or 1.6180.. exactly

> Note this golden ratio construction has been dramatically updated
> here with numerous golden harmonies:
> [A Golden Ratio Symphony! Why so many golden ratios in a relatively simple golden ratio construction with square and circle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803934/a-golden-ratio-symphony-why-so-many-golden-ratios-in-a-relatively-simple-golden?noredirect=1#comment3684815_1803934)

Have you seen the attached golden ratio construction before?  Three squares (or just two) and circle. For the ratio of segment t to segment a, Geogebra gives PHI or 1.6180.. exactly.

Geometric and trigonometric proofs are welcome!  Have you seen this construction before?[image: golden ratio construction]

This construction can be made with two or three identical squares and a circle.  Let us use two squares.  Begin with the two squares poly2 and poly1.  Then draw a circle intersecting points C, D, and E.  Then draw a segment from A to G.  The segment will be cut in the golden ratio by the arc of the circle so that the ratio of a to t is 1.618 or PHI.

Has anyone seen this golden ratio construction (or something similar), or might anyone see a more obvious or simpler way of constructing it?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Completing a $3$-by-$3$ grid of squares, and assigning their *diagonals* length $1$, gives this:

[image]

Here, we see the classical geometric mean construction that tells us
$$\frac{|\overline{PA}|}{|\overline{PC}|} = \frac{|\overline{PC}|}{|\overline{PA^\prime}|} \qquad\to\qquad \frac{a}{1} = \frac{1}{a+1} \tag{$\star$}$$

This relation says exactly that $a = \phi^{-1} = 0.618\dots$, the reciprocal of the [Golden Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio). Moreover, $b = 1-a = \phi^{-2}$, so that 
$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{\phi^{-1}}{\phi^{-2}} = \phi = 1.618\dots \qquad \square$$

---

As for whether the construction is novel ... Lore about the Golden Ratio is very wide, very deep, and very old. Discovering something that has never been seen before almost-certainly requires a great deal more complexity than appears in the constructions you've been posting here. That shouldn't discourage you from exploring and having fun, though. Each construction you discover *is* a laudable achievement. (I have enjoyed them ... when they've been valid. ;) As the late, great Steve Fisk told newbie undergrad me under very comparable circumstances: *It's just an accident of time that someone else discovered these things before you.*

Comment: Thanks @Blue !! :) Yes even the ones that appear novel may be very close to those that came before.  I love searching the internet too for any prior similar constructions.  I am learning a lot from your mathematical treatments, so thanks so much!  Geogebra has helped me throw a lot of "constructions" out, even when they are very close.  :)  Here's one page which I check for any similar prior constructions: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/GoldenRatio.shtml  The bottom of page has a list.  Didn't see anything similar there.

Comment: Really good quote at the end!